# MySQL with UNITY5

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game developed in UNITY 5, and I am integrating MySQL in the As my database manager. I want to know, how do I make an entire variable saved in the database without having to press a save button ?, That is saved automatically, Or is there a simpler way to save the data of the simplest integer variable? automatic way ?. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean an entire variable? If you don't want to press the save button then put it on a timer.

Comment: Without a Save button makes where this code would go even broader.  Can you post the section of code where you are wanting to save?

Comment: If, by "entire variable" you mean a class you have created, then you can look into JSON.Net to serialize your data, pass that data to a PHP/ASP Web API, or whatever server-side language you prefer, and insert it into your database that way using a POST request.